# How to update a fragment view in a view pager with a pagertabstrip?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I would like to share this knowledge. I think this question is in different places but I would like to answer it in a clear manner. I want to refresh the view of a fragment (textviews, buttons, etc..) that is inside of a view pager. How?

Answer (score 1):

There are different approximations, one of the most efficient is this:

1) Change the extends of the custom adapter class to FragmentStatePagerAdapter".

2) In the setOnPageChangeListener of your view pager, in the onPageSelected method, do:

```
if (position == 0) {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

where position is the position of the fragment that you would like to refresh its view and adapter is your adapter previously defined.

3) In your custom view pager class override this method:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof UpdateableFragment) {
        ((UpdateableFragment) object).update();
    }
    //don't return POSITION_NONE, avoid fragment recreation.
    return super.getItemPosition(object);    
}
```

4) Implement UpdateableFragment in the fragment that you want to refresh (position 0 in the example):

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements UpdateableFragment {
```

and add this method in the UpdateableFragment implementation:

```
@Override
public void update() {
    // Do your update code here
}
```

5) That's all. Enjoy. Hope this can help.